# Flash Builder 4 maxDisplayedLines comes back Error #2007 Parameter child must be non-null

Tags: flash, mobile, rss, richtext, rss-reader

I'm fairly new to flash builder and have made a working RSS feed reader, but I can't get the maxDisplayedLines to truncate the text at the end of my RichText object. It comes up with Error #2007 Paramater child must be non-null but I don't have a clue what would be null. The text I'm displaying is coming from textflow

```
textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(rdesc, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}"
```

and everything displays fine, even the thumbnails until I try to set the max lines. This is for mobile by the way.

the error is 
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at flashx.textLayout.factory::TextFlowTextLineFactory/callbackWithTextLines()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\factory\TextFlowTextLineFactory.as:267]
    at flashx.textLayout.factory::TextFlowTextLineFactory/createTextLinesInternal()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\factory\TextFlowTextLineFactory.as:245]
    at flashx.textLayout.factory::TextFlowTextLineFactory/createTextLines()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\factory\TextFlowTextLineFactory.as:104]
    at spark.components::RichText/createTextLines()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichText.as:1296]
    at spark.components::RichText/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::composeTextLines()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichText.as:1173]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::TextBase/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\TextBase.as:685]
    at spark.components::RichText/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichText.as:1131]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8999]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:736]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:819]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]

Answer (score 0):

```
 html text show in mobile textarea.

 <s:TextArea id="ric" width="200" height="100"/>

 var textrichtml:String = "<p><b>Scott Carpenter Architect Pty Ltd is a design based</p>";
 TextField(ric.textDisplay).htmlText = textrichtml;
```

Comment: thanks for the help. when I do that it comes back with what i think is the same error.

Comment: Pls textarea instead of richText component. Ive edit my answer .

Comment: when I ran it with TextArea instead it didn't show any text. it says TextFlow for TextArea isn't supported for mobile.  Is there no way to make it work with the RichText component? It was displaying thumbnail images in the RichText and I'd prefer not to lose that

Comment: Ive write htmltext show in textbox in another way. is it u want exactly? Pls look answer

Comment: now I get Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText@b5f4479 to flash.text.TextField. I have an RSS reader that will be for android working and what I'm trying to do is make the text stop and have a "..." when the stories are too long rather than just cutting off